# Pandas read_excel returns columns of type object

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, types

Using the following code to read in a table from Excel, discard a blank line under the column titles, and rename the Index:

```
Energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls', header=16, usecols="C:F", index_col=0, nrows=227)
Energy = Energy.iloc[1:,:]
Energy.index.rename('Country',inplace=True)
```

For an Excel table that looks like this:

[Excel table showing header and col names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6J9O.png)

This successfully returns the dataframe I need with the correct rows and columns. However, `Energy.dtypes` shows all columns to be objects, and I need the first column containing country names (which I've read as Index) to be type str. I tried `Energy.index.astype(str)` but still had "object" as the Index type. I tied adding `dtype={0:str}` to the read_excel call, but still has "object" as the Index type.

What is the correct method to either a) cause read_excel to return my Index as str; or b) convert index type to str?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define converters within the pd.read function:

```
Energy = pd.read_excel('assets/Energy Indicators.xls', header=16, usecols="C:F", index_col=0, nrows=227, converters={'my_column_name':str})
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.